# Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones (automatic weight painting error)

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, error

I was attempting to make an animatable 'humanoid' rig with rigfy. However I have ran into a problem that I am unable to find any solutions to.

Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones

**Without Rigfy:**

Front:
[image]

Side:
[image]

**With Rigfy:**

Front:
[image]

Side:
[image]

[This is a google drive folder that has the blender files.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1S2phZ_vODDNJlNZt-BtatT5pHiIXTSOI?usp=sharing)